# Jenkins Execution Issue

Tags: selenium, jenkins

A selenium script , when executing from Eclipse in a local machine , clicks an UPLOAD button in browser to upload some files from local machine to that application running in browser.

This uploading part is failing when the script is executing from Jenkins because Jenkins server is unable to access local machine.

Any idea how to overcome this issue..??

Answer (score 0):

Accessing these files from the server is a bad idea (unless it's a Jenkins's slave) though can be achieved via your code or some CMD tool, with providing the address and credentials. Put some effort in this and you'll find how to do it...

The better solutions will be adding these files to the Jenkins server as well or committing these files to your repository and checkout them before the test. 
A shared folder could also do the trick on a filer type server or similar.

Hope it helps. Anyway there's no substitute to your own research e.g. Google and StackOverflow.

Comment: I have tried keeping those files in eclipse workspace and providing that path in code but that also did not work..

Comment: Are you sure you provided the correct path? You didn't provide any details

Comment: Yes, I have used similar kind of path to read and write excel files during execution. 
This time difference is to upload a file.

Comment: Can't help you, you need to understand your problem first. Is it access local machine or your code fits to local machine but not to server? You didn't give any details...